# C#: Split 1D Array into 2D Array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 1D array:

```
string[] Technology = new [] {Smartphone, Laptop, Tablet, Desktop, Server, Mainframe};
```

How can I split this in half and put the two parts into a larger 2D array, such that the following both return `true`:

```
// categorizedTechnology[0].SequenceEquals(new [] {Smartphone, Laptop, Tablet});
// categorizedTechnology[1].SequenceEquals(new [] {Desktop, Server, Mainframe});
```

Comment: What is the logic used to categorize your technology?

Comment: @squillman The array is simply being split in two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have exactly 6 items you can do this:

```
string[] Technology = new string[6] { "Smartphone", "Laptop", "Tablet", "Desktop", "Server", "Mainframe" };

var firstChunk = Technology.Take(3);
var secondChunk = Technology.Skip(3).Take(3);

string[,] array2D = new string[,] { 
   { firstChunk.First(), firstChunk.Skip(1).First(), firstChunk.Last()},
   { secondChunk.First(), secondChunk.Skip(1).First(), secondChunk.Last()} };
```

OR simply do this:

```
string[,] array2D = new string[,] { 
        { Technology[0], Technology[1], Technology[2]},
        { Technology[3], Technology[4], Technology[5]} };
```

Comment: that will give him two one-dimensional arrays, not one two-dimensional

Comment: @Nino thanks. Edited my answer.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Thanks CodingYoshi!

Comment: You don't need the array size. Use `string[] technology = new string[] { "Smartphone", "Laptop", "Tablet", "Desktop", "Server", "Mainframe" };`. And variables are _not_ to be capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with specifying explicitly how many items go into which bin then you need to create another array holding the category. I choose to use an array of 'bool' to indicate if each item is portable or not. Then I zipped the two arrays together and filtered them as portable or not.

```
string[] technology = new string[] { "Smartphone", "Laptop", "Tablet", "Desktop", "Server", "Mainframe" };
bool[] isPortable = new bool[] { true, true, true, false, false, false };
string[][] categorizedTechnology = new string[][] 
{
    technology.Zip(isPortable, (tech, test)=> test?tech: null).Where( tech=> tech!=null ).ToArray(),
    technology.Zip(isPortable, (tech, test)=> test?null: tech).Where( tech=> tech!=null ).ToArray()
};
```

But this is still not the correct what of doing this. Here is where object oriented programming is important as the technology is category information *needs to be combined into a single entity* like a class, or structure.

This is what it would look like using classes and LINQ

```
public class Technology
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsPortable { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Technology[] list = new Technology[] {
            new Technology() { Name="Smartphone", IsPortable=true },
            new Technology() { Name="Laptop", IsPortable=true },
            new Technology() { Name="Tablet", IsPortable=true },
            new Technology() { Name="Desktop",  IsPortable=false },
            new Technology() { Name="Server",   IsPortable=false },
            new Technology() { Name="Mainframe", IsPortable=false },
        };

        Technology[][] groupedTechnology 
            = list.GroupBy((tech) => tech.IsPortable)
                .Select((group) => group.ToArray()).ToArray();
    }
}
```